# Comparar 4 Variáveis e executar o codigo único para cada resultado

Tags: if, shell, else, do-while

Olá, estou tentando criar uma comparação onde a ação seguinte será diferente para cada valor de variável alguem pode me ajudar.

O intuito é se se o valor for verdadeiro, executa uma função se for falso executa outra, porem preciso comparar 4 variaveis no mesmo bloco somente 1 pode ser verdadeira as demais tem que retornar falso.

**Segue me código:**

## atributos telefones de cada servidor

act1="$vartest1"
act2="$vartest2"
act3="$vartest3"
act4="$vartest4"

if [ "$act1" == "teste" ]
then
echo "Verdade"
else
echo "Falso"

elif [ "$act2" == "false" ]
then
echo "Falso"
sleep 1s
else
echo "Verdade"

elif [ "$act2" == "false" ]
then
echo "Falso"
else
echo "Verdade"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar a sintaxe de IF, usando a lógica do OU, aonde ele será basicamente assim

```
act1="$vartest1" act2="$vartest2" act3="$vartest3" act4="$vartest4"

if [ "$act1" == "teste" ou "$act2" == "true" ] 
  then 
     echo "Verdade" else echo "Falso"
     if["$act2" == "true"]
       sleep 1s else echo "Verdade"

elif [ "$act2" == "false" ] then echo "Falso" else echo "Verdade"
```

eu não entendo de shell, porém a base de lógica é a mesma para toda linguagem e sistema.

Comment: testei aqui nao deu certo em shell usamos elif eu queria comparar o resultados se 4 váriaveis  diferentes somente 1 for true ele executa o comando se não ele executa outro comando.

Comment: Até aonde eu sei seria pela sintaxe do if mesmo, você poderia usar o case, por exemplo, porém eu utilizo ele em JS não sei se tem em Shel